# Vertical Recyclerview only allow scrolling down but block scrolling up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I limit the scrolling ability of a vertical Recyclerview to only allow scrolling down?

I want to make somehow a "list with no return to the top".

EDIT: It's not a duplicate. I don't want to disable scrolling vertically. I just want to disable scrolling upwards.

Comment: AFAIK you can do this using `onScrollChange` listener `onScrollStateChanged` you gets the value of vertical scroll i.e. `dy` it'll let you know it's a fling up or fling down. Now you know it's a fling up, explicitly move your `recylerview` to the bottom using `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);`

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution using an OnItemTouchListener.

The scrolling event consists of 3 MotionEvents : `ACTION_DOWN` , `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP`.

So on `ACTION_DOWN` we get the vertical position of the cursor (Y) and the on `ACTION_MOVE` we compare the new position to the old one.

By returning `true`, the method onInterceptTouchEvent() makes sure we intercept  the scrolling event.

```
float lastY;

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            lastY = event.getY();
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && event.getY() > lastY) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer I will try it out now.

Comment: This answer has the problem if I swipe down but keep my finger on swiping down I can also swipe up again.